# Collecting event logs

Tags: powershell, windows-10, event-log

I want to collect all the event logs since a defined timestamp. Here there is my chunck code:

```
$StartTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)

$rawdata = Get-WinEvent -ListLog *

$eventlogs = @{}

foreach ($record in $rawdata) {
    if ($record.LastWriteTime -gt $StartTime) {
        $eventlogs[$record.GetHashCode()] = @{
            'LogType' = $record.LogType
            'Name' = $record.LogName
            'Provider' = $record.OwningProviderName
            'Path' = $record.LogFilePath
            'Mode' = $record.LogMode
            'Time' = $record.LastWriteTime
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to the above info, how can I retrieve a full extended description of each event log? I would like to avoid parsing each single .evtx file

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do that is to use FilterXml parameter of Get-WinEvent.
You can actually create your filter by creating a filter using Event Viewer:

[image]

[image]

After that you copy > paste that in PowerShell. Also you will need to escape single quotation marks that surround time '2021-11-23T10:00:00.000Z' should become ''2021-11-23T10:00:00.000Z'' . NB, those are 2 * ', not double quote ".
Of course if you want to pass dates via variable, you can do that by using Get-Date

```
$filterXml = '
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;=''2021-11-23T10:00:00.000Z'' and @SystemTime&lt;=''2021-11-23T14:03:00.999Z'']]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>'

Get-WinEvent –FilterXml $filterXml
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about reading extended descriptions, but you can read the event log with the following. Note logname allows wild cards, thus the *.

```
$time = (get-date).AddMinutes(-5)
Get-WinEvent  –FilterHashtable @{logname='*'; starttime=$time}
```

Comment: * as logname won't work.  There's some kind of api limit.  You'll have to use a foreach-object loop instead.  PS 7 gives a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with a chunk of code like this one I have written:

```
    # get events log
    Write-Host -NoNewline "Retrieving events log... "
    $logtime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)
    $eventlogs.Clear()
    $string = ''
    $ErrorActionPreference= 'SilentlyContinue'
    foreach ($logtype in ('System', 'Security','Application')) {
        $rawdata = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName=$logtype; StartTime=$logtime}
        foreach ($record in $rawdata) {
            $logkey = '[' + $record.LogName + ']_'
            $logkey += Get-Date $record.TimeCreated -format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-fff"
            $record.Message -match "^(.*)\r+" > $null
            if ($matches[1]) {
                $string = $matches[1]
                $matches[1] = $null
            } else {
                $record.Message -match "^(.*)\n+" > $null
                if ($matches[1]) {
                    $string = $matches[1]
                    $matches[1] = $null
                } else {
                    $string = $record.Message
                }
            }
            $eventlogs[$logkey] = @{
                'Name' = $record.LogName
                'Time' = Get-Date $record.TimeCreated -format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"
                'Id' = $record.Id
                'Message' = $string
                'Type' = $record.LevelDisplayName
            }
        }
    }
    $ErrorActionPreference= 'Inquire'
    $logfile = $logpath + '\' + $timestamp + '_EventLogs.csv' 
    'ID;LOGTYPE;NAME;TIME;MESSAGE' | Out-File $logfile -Encoding UTF8 -Append
    foreach ($item in ($eventlogs.Keys | Sort-Object)) {
        $new_record = @(
            $eventlogs[$item].Id,
            $eventlogs[$item].Type,
            $eventlogs[$item].Name,
            $eventlogs[$item].Time,
            $eventlogs[$item].Message  
        )
        $new_string = [system.String]::Join(";", $new_record)
        $new_string | Out-File $logfile -Encoding UTF8 -Append
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'DONE'
```

For convenience I will catch only the first line of the message. In order to get this I have adopted the following block:

```
            $record.Message -match "^(.*)\r+" > $null
            if ($matches[1]) {
                $string = $matches[1]
                $matches[1] = $null
            } else {
                $record.Message -match "^(.*)\n+" > $null
                if ($matches[1]) {
                    $string = $matches[1]
                    $matches[1] = $null
                } else {
                    $string = $record.Message
                }
            }
```

Such solution is due to the fact that some messages use `\r\n`, others only `\n` and still others I don't know. This last block does not satisfy me, even if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply getting all recent logs, working within the windows api limits.  For some reason it still says ProviderName in the headers.

```
$time = (get-date).AddMinutes(-5)
get-winevent -listlog * | % { Get-WinEvent @{logname=$_.logname;
  starttime=$time} -ea 0} | ft -GroupBy logname


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Operational

TimeCreated                      Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                      -- ---------------- -------
11/27/2021 10:52:54 AM         5857 Information      Win32_WIN32_TERMINALSERVICE_Prov provider started with result c...
11/27/2021 10:52:54 AM         5857 Information      CIMWin32 provider started with result code 0x0. HostProcess = w...
11/27/2021 10:51:59 AM         5857 Information      StateMessageProvider provider started with result code 0x0. Hos...
```

% -parallel works even better in ps 7.

```
get-winevent -logname *
Get-WinEvent: Log count (458) is exceeded Windows Event Log API limit (256). Adjust filter to return less log names.

$time = (get-date).AddMinutes(-5)
get-winevent -listlog * | % -parallel { Get-WinEvent @{logname=$_.logname;
  starttime=$using:time} -ea 0} | ft -GroupBy logname
```